# Submitting WordPress blog to Flipboard

Tags: wordpress, flipboard

Does anyone know of a simple way to submit my blog feed to flipboard?

It requires things like the entire post in the rss feed.
Whole list here: https://flipboard.com/rss

I already have a feed running through feed burner. Is it possible to have two? One for normal subscribers and one for flipboard? I imagine one for both wouldn't work too well?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way to have a dedicated feed just for Flipboard.  They do require an optimized RSS feed which WordPress does not meet the requirements.

I did a quick Google search for a plugin since that would be a simple way to implement what you need and I came across this plugin called [Flipboard RSS Feed + Shortcode](http://codecanyon.net/item/flipboard-rss-feed-shortcode/5408507). I do not have any experience with it though.  The dev site can be found [here](http://www.netgrid.it/prodotti/all-in-one-flipboard-integration/).  I would read more in to it and make sure it solves the problem.

If that was what you were looking for go ahead and mark this answered.  Let me know how it works if you use it.  Looks pretty interesting.